# R Select row with min value greater than zero using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Attempting to group rows by x and selecting row with the minimum value greater than zero

```
 x  Start Time      End Time        Time_Diff
 A  01-01-17 0:14   01-01-17 0:14   3
 A  01-01-17 0:14   01-01-17 21:51  77817
 B  01-01-17 15:59  01-01-17 7:22   -31042
 B  01-01-17 15:59  01-01-17 16:25  1574
```

Attempted:

```
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    slice(which.min(as.numeric(Time_Diff)))
```

However, it returns the negative values. This is the solution I'm expecting. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 x  Start Time      End Time        Time_Diff 
 A  01-01-17 0:14   01-01-17 0:14   3
 B  01-01-17 15:59  01-01-17 16:25  1574
```

Comment: Add `filter( Time_Diff > 0 ) %>%` before your `slice()` call.

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this also works

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter( Time_Diff > 0 ) %>%
  arrange(desc(as.numeric(Time_Diff))) %>%
  slice(n = n())
```